# Partial Mock or new class or what else?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, mocking

I have a question about testing.

I have a class that returns anomalies. in this class I have two different method that simply returns two different types of anomalies and one that return all anomalies (of both types)

this is the example code:

```
 public interface IAnomalyService
{
    IList<Anomaly> GetAllAnomalies(object parameter1, object parameter2);
    IList<Anomaly> GetAnomalies_OfTypeA(object parameter1);
    IList<Anomaly> GetAnomalies_OfTypeB(object parameter2);
}
public class AnomalyService : IAnomalyService
{
    public IList<Anomaly> GetAllAnomalies(object parameter1, object parameter2)
    {
        var lstAll = new List<Anomaly>();
        lstAll.AddRange(GetAnomalies_OfTypeA(parameter1));
        lstAll.AddRange(GetAnomalies_OfTypeB(parameter2));
        return lstAll;
    }
    public IList<Anomaly> GetAnomalies_OfTypeA(object parameter1)
    {
        //some elaborations
        return new List<Anomaly> { new Anomaly { Id = 1 } };
    }
    public IList<Anomaly> GetAnomalies_OfTypeB(object parameter2)
    {
        //some elaborations
        return new List<Anomaly> { new Anomaly { Id = 2 } };
    }
}

class Anomaly
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

I've created the tests for the two method that retrieve the anomalies of type A and type B (GetAnomalies_OfTypeA and GetAnomalies_OfTypeB).
Now I want to test the function GetAllAnomalies but I'm not sure what I have to do.

I think I have to way for testing it:
1) declare GetAnomalies_OfTypeA and GetAnomalies_OfTypeB in class AnomalyService as virtual, make a mock of the Class AnomalyService, and using Moq I can set CallBase as true and mock the two method GetAnomalies_OfTypeA and GetAnomalies_OfTypeB.

2)move the method GetAllAnomalies in another class called AllAnomalyService (with interface IAllAnomalyService) and in its constructor I will pass an interface of IAnomalyService and after I can test the GetAllAnomalies mocking the IAnomalyService interface.

I'm new at unit testing, so I don't know which solution is better, if is one of the mines or another one.
Can you help me?

thank you
Luca

Answer (score 0):

Mocking is a good tool when a class resists testing. If you have the source, mocking is often not necessary. Try this approach:

- Create a factory which can return `AnomalyService`s with various, defined anomalies (only type A, only type B, both, none, only type C, ...)
- Since the three types are connected in some way, you should check all three in each test. If only anomalies of type A are expected, you should check that `GetAllAnomalies` returns the same result as `GetAnomalies_OfTypeA` and `GetAnomalies_OfTypeB` returns an empty list.

Comment: Sorry but I haven't understood what you mean for create a factory.
I've already create the unit testing for the GetAnomalies_OfTypeA and GetAnomalies_OfTypeB so I don't want to test anymore when i test GetAllAnomalies. What I want to test, is that inside the method "getallanomalies" I don't forget to call GetAnomalies_OfTypeA and GetAnomalies_OfTypeB. My intentions was to mock something, so that GetAnomaliesOfTypeA returns 3 anomalies, oftypeb return 4 anomalies, and when I call getallanomalies I have to check that it returns 7 anomalies

Comment: Move the code which set up `AnomalyService` for the first unit test into a factory. Ideally, the factory should work like this: "add 1 anomalies of type A and 3 of type B and return the service" That allows you to create any number of anomalies of any type and then test that the service works correctly for them. Goal: The set up code in your test should be 1 line.